# Vaadin URL Mapping

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is there a way do not enter a specifc url mapping (vaadin.urlMapping)? But I also want to still use swagger for example (ip:8080/swagger-ui/index.html)? It would be great to exclude some mappings from vaadin.

Thanks for your help!

Best Regards, Thomas

Comment: Can you help clarify the question a bit more? Do I understand correctly that you want your Vaadin app to be available on `/`, but have it ignore `/swagger-ui/*`?

Comment: Hello Marcus! Correct, this is exactly the requirement I have. Best Regards, Thomas

Comment: I spent some time trying to achieve this. The suggestion I got was to swap the priority of handler mappings so that swagger-ui is handled before Vaadin stuff. but I couldn't get it to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the **URL/Part of URL/IP** in the **properties file**.
2. Put the **URL/Part of URL/IP** in the **web.xml file**.

In some cases you want **the remote URL to be different than the local URL** (**or remote SSL URL to be different than the local URL**).
In that case, I **placed both IP and domain on to web.xml in two different contexts.**

```
final String serverUrl = new URL("" + ((VaadinServletRequest)VaadinService.getCurrentRequest())
                    .getHttpServletRequest().getRequestURL()).getAuthority();
final String  serverProtocol =
                    ((VaadinServletRequest)VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()).getHttpServletRequest().getProtocol();
final boolean serverSecure   =
            ((VaadinServletRequest)VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()).getHttpServletRequest().isSecure();
if(!serverSecure){
UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(
    ResourceProperty.configBundle.getString("APPLICATION_URL"),
    "http:" + serverUrl);}
else{
UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute(
    ResourceProperty.configBundle.getString("APPLICATION_URL"),
    "https:" + serverUrl);}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it is not clear to me how to work with your code above. Currently I have the property vaadin.urlMapping set to no specifc path in application.properties file. In this case other mappings like "/swagger-ui/*" does not longer work, because Vaadin catch all mappings. By changing the parameter to "vaadin.urlMapping=/ui/*" the swagger mapping is working, but this is not my goal. The goal is to do not have any specific mapping for Vaadin. Best Regards, Thomas

Comment: It was possible in Rapidclipse 4 with Vaadin 8 but I don't know if that is possible with Vaadin 14. Before I migrated my project to Rapidclipse X. Our URL used to be like http://localhost:8080/Project no matter where you have visited the URL never used to show any mapping. I think you want to achieve the same thing in RapidclipseX with Vaadin 14. Is that right?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand correctly your question. With vaadin 8 it was possible to have a URL without a specifc mapping. In Vaadin 14/19 I have to add the application property, otherwise swagger is not longer working because vaadin catch all mappings.

Comment: I tried the last days/weeks a lot to fulfill this requirement, but unfortunately with no luck. Does anyone else have maybe an idea how to handle this? Thanks! :)